# appendTo not working as expected

Tags: jquery, append, appendto

I have a simple UL with all LI's having class="event".

The following jQuery is not working as expected.

```
$('#calendar-feed li.event').each(function() {
    $(this).find('h3').appendTo('h4');
});
```

I'd like to take the only h3 in every LI and append it to the only h4 in that LI.

Currently it is taking all the H3s and cloning them into each H4.

Is my syntax just wrong or am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this, because the `appendTo` is a new selector which can contain anything within the page. So you were selecting all H4 within the page and added them to the LI h3.

```
$('#calendar-feed li.event').each(function() {
    $(this).find('h3').appendTo($(this).find('h4'));
});
```

Comment: This worked.  I have a decent working knowledge of jQuery, but I don't have the mind of a programmer...  For whatever reason I was thinking because it was in a .each function it would only look in that particular LI.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to get the correct `h4` inside the loop, something like this:

```
$('#calendar-feed li.event').each(function() {
    var h4 = $(this).find('h4');
    $(this).find('h3').appendTo(h4);
});
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/CGb2A/)

Comment: I didn't try this particular solution, but I imagine it would also work, seeing now what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense appending an `<h3>` **INTO** `<h4>`.

I guess what you want is to place `<h3>` **AFTER** `<h4>`, swapping their positions (although it still makes less sense if you're using these tags, but anyway)

```
$('#calendar-feed li.event h3').each(function (i, h3) {
    var $h3 = $(h3);
    $h3.after($h3.closest('li').find('h4'));
});
```

---

Alternatively if you want the `<h3>` guaranteed to be the **last** element in each `<li>`, then do this

```
$('#calendar-feed li.event h3').each(function (i, h3) {
    var $h3 = $(h3);
    $h3.appendTo($h3.closest('li'));
});
```

---

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/terryyounghk/sN7Mf/

Comment: I do want the h3 INSIDE the h4.  mainly because of how I'm needing to style it, and I can't rewrite how CMS is writing out the markup.